# in shutil.rmtree() how to match the string?

Tags: python, shutil

In linux bash we can delete files through `rm -rf test_file*`,
but in Python `shutil.rmtree()`. How can we match the string through some thing like `*`?

Comment: You can use *glob* to match the files then delete them individually

Comment: [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) removes directory, not file. If you need to remove files by pattern, firstly retrieve all files using [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) / [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and remove each using [`os.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink) / [`Path.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink).

Answer (score 2):

None of the functions in the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module expand the path. It's possible to use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) module and then call `shutil.rmtree` on each result:

```py
import shutil

from glob import glob

for match in glob('test_file*'):
   shutil.rmtree(match)
```

Alternatively you can call directly `rm` using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could do this:

```
import os
from glob import glob

for file in glob('test_file*'):
    os.remove(file)
```